# Recursively removing duplicate characters in a string

Tags: c, recursion, c-strings, function-definition

I'm trying to create a recursive function which removes the consecutive duplicate characters from a string. It works fine except the first few characters. For example if my input is `MMMMMuuuuuOOOOOKKKKLLLEE OOOOLLL` or something like this, output is `MMuOKLE OL`. As you can see except for the first two M's it works fine. How can I make this work for the first part too?
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* remove_duplicates (char* str){
    if(*(str+1)!='\0'){
        if(*str==*(str+1)){
            *(str+1)=*(str+2);
             remove_duplicates(str+1);
        }
        remove_duplicates(str+1);
    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char sample[] = "MMMMMuuuuuOOOOOKKKKLLLEE OOOOLLL";

    printf("OLD: |%s|\n", sample);
    printf("NEW: |%s|\n", remove_duplicates(sample));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to whatever else might be wrong, what happens if you pass an empty string (`""`) to `remove_duplicates()`?

Comment: Simplify the test case to the minimal string needed to see the problem. Then walk thru it on paper and step thru it in a debugger.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I passed `""` to `remove_duplicates()` in main. Nothing happpens. It prints the menu again.

Comment: @gokbeykeskin - I believe you need to look at this more closely. What causes the function to stop if the first character is a NUL byte, and everything after it is random junk?

Comment: what interrest to return the argument rather than to have `void remove_duplicates(char * str)`  ? that make the second call non terminal for nothing

Comment: @gokbeykeskin You marked as the nest answer the answer with invalid code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * remove_duplicates( char *s )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        if ( *s == *( s + 1 ) )
        {
            *( s + 1 ) = *( s + 2 );
            remove_duplicates( s + 1 );
            remove_duplicates( s );
        }
        else
        {
            remove_duplicates( s + 1 );
        }           
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "MMMMMuuuuuOOOOOKKKKLLLEE";

    remove_duplicates( s );

    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
MuOKLE
```

Comment: The logic is painful `:)` -- but then again, all recursive logic with multiple recursive calls is.... Well done.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* remove_duplicates(char* str)
{
    if (*str)
    {
        char* dest = remove_duplicates(str + 1);
        str = (*str == *dest) ? dest : ((*(dest - 1) = *str), (dest - 1));
    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char sample[] = "MMMMMuuuuuOOOOOKKKKLLLEE OOOOLLL";
    char sample2[] = "AA";

    printf("OLD: |%s|\n", sample);
    printf("NEW: |%s|\n", remove_duplicates(sample));

    printf("OLD: |%s|\n", sample2);
    printf("NEW: |%s|\n", remove_duplicates(sample2));

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
OLD: |MMMMMuuuuuOOOOOKKKKLLLEE OOOOLLL|
NEW: |MuOKLE OL|
OLD: |AA|
NEW: |A|
```

Comment: Interesting, it shifts non-duplicates to the end and then returns a pointer within the string where the non-duplicates start, but the original string (e.g. if you print `sample` again) still contains the duplicates.

Comment: @abelenky You provided a wrong code. Try the following char sample[] = "AA"; remove_duplicates( sample ); printf( "\"%s\"\n", sample );

Comment: @Vlad:  My code does modify `sample` in place, but it returns a pointer to the proper part of the array.   You should try `printf("\"%s\"\n", remove_duplicates(sample));` and you will see the return value is correct.

Comment: @abelenky This is an invalid approach. You have to remove duplicates from the original string pointed to by the pointer passed to the function as an argument.

Comment: @Vlad That is not specified in the problem description.  My return value is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I walked through my code on paper as you said and realised the problem is it doesn't compare the first and last M. 
I add a new if statement `if(*str==*(str-1)) *(str)=*(str+1);` and it works now.

Now function is:

```
char* remove_duplicates (char* str){
    if(*(str+1)!='\0'){
        if(*str==*(str+1)){
            *(str+1)=*(str+2);
            remove_duplicates(str+1);
        }
        remove_duplicates(str+1);
    }
    if(*str==*(str-1)) *(str)=*(str+1);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am here just adding the recursive function (language: C++) and not the entire code.

```
void removeConsecutiveDuplicates(char input[]) {
   
    if(input[0] == '\0' || input[1]=='\0') return;
    if(input[0]!=input[1]) return removeConsecutiveDuplicates(input+1);
    else
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=strlen(input);i++)
        {
            input[i-1] = input[i];
        }
       return removeConsecutiveDuplicates(input);
    }  
    return; 
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem? Check this [help center erticle](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code.

Answer (score -1):

Recursion is too complicated I think.

Lets start with 2 cursor at the begining of the `str`

First a loop on the string.
While we don't reach the end `*p` of the string look forward `p++`

```
while (*p++) {
    if (*p == *current)
        continue;
```

If next char is the same as the current continue to search the next different char.

```
current++;
*current = *p;
```

When a different char is found just put it after current.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* remove_duplicates (char* str){
    char *p = str;
    char *current = p;
    while (*p++) {
        if (*p == *current)
            continue;
        current++;
        *current = *p;
    }

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char sample[] = "MMMMMuuuuuOOOOOKKKKLLLEE OOOOLLL";

    printf("OLD: |%s|\n", sample);
    printf("NEW: |%s|\n", remove_duplicates(sample));
    printf("NEW: |%s|\n", remove_duplicates(""));

    return 0;
}


OLD: |MMMMMuuuuuOOOOOKKKKLLLEE OOOOLLL|
NEW: |MuOKLE OL|
NEW: ||
```

Detail with `AAAB`
c for current

```
p
v
AAAB0
^
c

   p
   v
AAAB0
^
c

   p
   v
AAAB0
 ^
 c

   p
   v
ABAB0
 ^
 c

    p
    v
ABAB0
 ^
 c


    p
    v
ABAB0
  ^
  c


    p
    v
AB0B0
  ^
  c
```

We get `AB`

Comment: Too complicated?  My function is 4 lines of code in a single if-statement, and is recursive, as requested.

Comment: @abelenky See comment from  David C. Rankin, I think recursive on this topic is not simple, 4 lines and a big ternary not sure it is simple.